# The Use of "Continue"

Tags: java, continue

Can someone explain the intuition behind this code here:

```
class ContDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i;
        // print even numbers between 0 and 100
        for (i = 0; i<=100; i++) {
            if ((i%2) != 0) continue; // iterate
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I really don't understand the logic behind it. Would someone please help me?

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: You want even numbers; Therefore if they are divisible by 2, you show them. To do so, you take their modulos. As pointed by Eran, the design there isn't even any point using 'continue'. Continue only skips the rest of the loop and goes for the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example, there's not much point in using `continue`, since you can simply replace it with :

```
for (i = 0; i<=100; i++) {
    if ((i%2) == 0)
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Or even better drop the "if"  and change i++ with i+=2

Answer (score 1):

As the title of the question says, "The use of Continue.. .", so here is an explanation. 
The statement,

```
continue;
```

is used whenever we need to continue a loop without executing the statements below the

```
continue;
```

statement. For instance, have a look at the following code:

```
for (i = 0; i<=10; i++) {
        System.out.printf(" "+i);
        if (i>4)
            continue;
        System.out.println(" is less than 5");
    }
```

Output:

```
 0 is less than 5
 1 is less than 5
 2 is less than 5
 3 is less than 5
 4 is less than 5
 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Whenever the if(i>4) block is executed, the statements below the

```
continue;
```

statement do not execute.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the continue keyword in the f.f.g code:

```
class ContDemo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int i;
    // print even numbers between 0 and 100
    for(i = 0; i<=100; i++) {
      if((i%2) != 0) continue; // iterate
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Isn't necessary but the purpose of it without a label is to process the condition the loop is dealing with. Such as the for loop just used, the continue keyword( when executed will re - execute the condition and start executing statements from the condition.

Examples: in the f.f.g code

```
for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++){
   continue;
   int a = 1;
}
```

the `continue` statement will lead to the condition constantly being executed (the counter will be incremented) and when it reaches ten the loop will end.

```
int a = 1;// will never be executed.It will seen as an unreachable statement by the compiler.
```

`continue` is different from `break` as the break keyword end the loop immediately when it is executed

forgive my grammar if any errors. I welcome edits. Hope this helps.

Comment: There is a little mistake here: in Java, after a keyword such as continue or break, you can't have code that would not be reachable. It is an error, and it is reported by the compiler. Hence, the `int a = 1;` after the `continue` **is** an error.

Comment: I believe it doesn't return an error when if statements are used.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I made the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

"continue" jumps back to the start of a loop (but does not restart the loop...)
"break" immediately exits a loop.